# phpMyAdmin にログインできない

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin にログインできません。MySQL の設定のせいかもしれませんが、ご教示ください。

phpMyAdmin 4.4.14.1 をダウンロードし、ウェブサーバに設置しました。
参考 http://pocolog.cocolog-nifty.com/mt/2014/07/vps-phpmyadmin-.html
ユーザー phpmyadmin でログインしようとすると、「#1045 MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示されます。

MySQL にユーザの設定をしていなかったからと考え、とりあえず root で入れるように設定しました。
参考 http://www.goofoo.jp/2011/11/1457
参考 http://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/user/index1.html
参考 http://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/user/index2.html
参考サイトの違いは、user が複数いたので user を削除するのは思いとどまったのと、root が user にいなかったので、admin のパスワードを設定したことです。

それで、phpMyAdmin の画面を表示させて、ユーザー : admin, パスワード : phpMyPassword(mysql で設定したパスワード) と入力しても「 #1045 MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示させます。

Comment: エラーの追跡に役立つ情報を追記していただけると回答が付きやすくなります。例えば、ご使用のサーバーやネットワーク環境、OSとミドルウェア、ログファイルの内容、設定ファイル(config.inc.php、php.iniなど)の内容など追記できますか？` select host, user from user;`の結果も書いていただけると良いなと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
あれから色々いじってサーバが汚くなったので、OS を再インスールしました。
こんどは大丈夫でした。

Answer (score 2):

外しているかもしれませんが、ユーザを追加された際のホスト名の設定はどうなっていますか？
phpMyAdminを表示する際のURLのホスト名と、データベースに登録されたユーザのホスト名が違っているとアクセスできません。

同じサーバを指すとしても、自端末のhostsファイルにしか登録されていないエイリアスなどだと、接続できなくてよくハマります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。結局サーバを再インストールしました。
CentOS 6.4 にしたところ、無事ログインできました。